# How do I use localized strings in handlebar templates?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Say I had a view like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="say-hello">
  Hello, <b>{{name}}</b>
</script>
```

How would I localize the word "Hello," using the built in Ember.String.loc()? I am not seeing a solution in the documentation/code.

Comment: You might want to look into [ember-i18n](https://github.com/zendesk/ember-i18n) project or [i18n-js](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js)

Comment: Hmm, seems heavy-weight, why wouldn't I write a simple localization helper:

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe localization helper: https://gist.github.com/3093861

Comment: @PulletsForever You should auto-reply your question, as the link you provided is a correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

I am now using built in localization.

To do so one would create a 'simple' view helper: http://gist.github.com/3093861:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('loc', function(property, fn) {
  var str;
  // we are bound to a value, it is now the context
  if (fn.contexts && typeof fn.contexts[0] === 'string') {
    str = fn.contexts[0];

  // Convention, start all localization keys with _
  } else if (property[0] === '_') {
    str = property;

  // Convention, start all globals with capital
  } else if (/[A-Z]/.test(property[0])) {
    str = Em.getPath(window, property)

  // all other's are local properties
  } else {
    str = this.getPath(property)
  }

  return new Handlebars.SafeString((str || '').loc(''));
});

// use:
// {{loc _some_string}}
// {{#bind App.someString}}{{loc App.someString}}{{/bind}}
// {{#bind view.localString}}{{loc view.localString}}{{/bind}}
```

But this is not as clean as it should be, note how bound values need to be wrapped in `{{#bind}}`

Still open to better options. (I think I can update the view helper to support bindings, but have not investigated further yet)

Comment: I'm dealing with similar issues ATM. I went with some server-side mangling of the templates (master English templates with extra markup so that a separate tool can extract the English and replace it with translated versions as needed). Keep in mind that you can't just translate "Hello" and paste it together with the name, you have to translate whole sentences.

Comment: Yeah, that is a another issue that my solution does not solve. I will need a way to format the localized string in the future and will need to look into updating the helper at that time.